# please draw flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
    \node (input) [io, below of=start] {Read Input};
    \node (i1) [process, below of=input] {$i = 1$};
    \node (matrix) [process, below of=i1] {Initialize \\ \texttt{matrix}};
    \node (matrix1) [process, below of=matrix] {Initialize \\ \texttt{matrix1}};
    \node (loop) [decision, below of=matrix1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Loop Condition \\ $i > 0$};
    \node (row) [io, below of=loop, yshift=-0.5cm] {Read Row};
    \node (check) [decision, below of=row, yshift=-0.5cm] {Check \\ $-1$};
    \node (invalid) [process, below of=check, yshift=-1cm] {Print \\ "Invalid Matrix"};
    \node (pop) [process, right of=check, xshift=3.5cm] {Pop Last Row};
    \node (valid) [process, below of=pop] {Append \\ to \texttt{matrix1}};
    \node (transpose) [process, below of=valid] {Transpose \\ Matrix};
    \node (print) [io, below of=transpose] {Print Transposed Matrix};
    \node (error) [process, below of=loop, xshift=-4cm, yshift=-3cm] {Print \\ "Error"};
    \node (stop) [startstop, below of=error] {Stop};
    
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (input);
    \draw [arrow] (input) -- (i1);
    \draw [arrow] (i1) -- (matrix);
    \draw [arrow] (matrix) -- (matrix1);
    \draw [arrow] (matrix1) -- (loop);
    \draw [arrow] (loop) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (row);
    \draw [arrow] (row) -- (check);
    \draw [arrow] (check) -- node[anchor=east] {no} (pop);
    \draw [arrow] (check) -- node[anchor=south] {yes} (invalid);
    \draw [arrow] (pop) -- (valid);
    \draw [arrow] (valid) -- (transpose);
    \draw [arrow] (transpose) -- (print);
    \draw [arrow] (loop.west) -| node[anchor=south] {no} ++(-1.5,0) |- (stop);
    \draw [arrow] (print.east) -- ++(1.5,0) |- (loop.east);
    \draw [arrow] (loop.south) -- node[anchor=east] {error} (error.north);
    \draw [arrow] (error) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Your question is hard to understand: what is missing, or what goes wrong? Can you please add a screenshot of your codes result? Thank you

Comment: The code compiles fine. Please explain what the expected output should be.

Comment: Please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

- Sorry, it is not entirely clear how your flowchart should looks. So, some arrows may be wrong oriented or missed.
- I guess that you may be after something like this:

[image]

- For above flowchart I additionally employ Ti*k*Z libraries `chains`, `ext.paths.ortho`,    `positioning` and `quotes`.
- For nodes positioning is used `chains` library.
- consecutive nodes in branches are connected by help of ˙join`macro defined in`chains` library.
- Arrows between other arrows are drawn separately, where are used arrows defined in `ext.paths.ortho` libraries.
- For use `ext.paths.ortho` library you need to have installed ext-tikz` package, available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en).

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en
                chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % defined in the tikz-ext package
                                    % https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 6 mm and 12 mm,
     arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
     lbl/.style = {inner sep=1pt, label=below right:#1},
    base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw,
                   text width=44mm, align=center, minimum height=1cm,
                   font=\sffamily},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
  process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
 decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.3, draw, fill=green!30,
                    minimum width=32mm, minimum height=1cm,
                    inner xsep=0pt, align=center}, 
       io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                    draw, fill=blue!30,
                    minimum width=44mm, minimum height=1cm,
                    text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}
                                    -2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                    align=center}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
                  nodes = {on chain, join=by arr}]
\node   [startstop]     {Start};
\node   [io]            {Read Input};
\node   [process]       {$i = 1$};
\node   [process]       {Initialize \\ \texttt{matrix}};
\node   [process]       {Initialize \\ \texttt{matrix1}};
\node (D1) [decision]   {Loop Condition \\ $i > 0$};
%    
\node   [suspend join,io]   {Read Row};
\node (D2) [decision]   {Check \\ $-1$};
\node    [process]      {Print \\ "Invalid Matrix"};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
                  nodes = {on chain, join=by arr}]
\node (Pr)  [process, right=of D2]   {Pop Last Row};
\node   [process]   {Append \\ to \texttt{matrix1}};
\node   [process]   {Transpose \\ Matrix};
\node (IO)  [io]        {Print Transposed Matrix};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
                  nodes = {on chain, join=by arr}]
\node  (print)  [process, left=of D2]   {Print \\ "Error"};
\node (stop)    [startstop]     {Stop};
    \end{scope}
% arrows not drawn by join macro
\draw[arr] (D2.east) node[lbl=above right:No] {} -- (Pr);
\node[lbl=below right:Yes] at (D2.south) {};
%
\draw[arr] (D1.south) node[lbl=below right:Yes] {} |-| [distance=3mm]  (print);
\draw[arr] (IO) r-rl    (D1);
\draw[arr] (D1.west)  node[lbl=above  left:No ] {} r-lr     (stop);
\draw[arr] (IO)     r-rl    (D1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- `tikzpicture` options can also be moved document in preamble (if you need this style settings also in other Ti*k*Z pictures) using in `\tikzset` :

```
% rest of preamble
% \usetikzlibrary{...}
\tizset{
% options from `tikzpicture
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

- Load the `positioning library`
- `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`
- `scale=.7, transform shape`
- `below=of start` or `below=1cm of start`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning}

\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, draw=black, fill=red!30},
    io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
    process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
    decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, draw=black, fill=green!30},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, transform shape, node distance=.5cm]
    \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
    \node (input) [io, below=of start] {Read Input};
    \node (i1) [process, below=of input] {$i = 1$};
    \node (matrix) [process, below=of i1] {Initialize \\ \texttt{matrix}};
    \node (matrix1) [process, below=of matrix] {Initialize \\ \texttt{matrix1}};
    \node (loop) [decision, below=of matrix1] {Loop Condition \\ $i > 0$};
    \node (row) [io, below=1cm of loop] {Read Row};
    \node (check) [decision, below=of row] {Check \\ $-1$};
    \node (invalid) [process, below=1cm of check] {Print \\ "Invalid Matrix"};
    \node (pop) [process, right=3cm of check] {Pop Last Row};
    \node (valid) [process, below=of pop] {Append \\ to \texttt{matrix1}};
    \node (transpose) [process, below=of valid] {Transpose \\ Matrix};
    \node (print) [io, below=of transpose] {Print Transposed Matrix};
    \node (error) [process, below left=3cm and 4cm of loop] {Print \\ "Error"};
    \node (stop) [startstop, below=of error] {Stop};
    
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (input);
    \draw [arrow] (input) -- (i1);
    \draw [arrow] (i1) -- (matrix);
    \draw [arrow] (matrix) -- (matrix1);
    \draw [arrow] (matrix1) -- (loop);
    \draw [arrow] (loop) -- node[right] {yes} (row);
    \draw [arrow] (row) -- (check);
    \draw [arrow] (check) -- node[above] {no} (pop);
    \draw [arrow] (check) -- node[right] {yes} (invalid);
    \draw [arrow] (pop) -- (valid);
    \draw [arrow] (valid) -- (transpose);
    \draw [arrow] (transpose) -- (print);
    \draw [arrow] (loop.west) -| node[anchor=south] {no} ++(-1.5,0) |- (stop);
    \draw [arrow] (print.east) -- ++(1.5,0) |- (loop.east);
    \draw [arrow] (loop.south) -| node[anchor=east] {error} (error.north);
    \draw [arrow] (error) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```